# Spring Boot 1.3 + OAuth: Authentication request failed: BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token

Tags: spring, grails, oauth

I'm trying to authenticate an OAuth Spring Boot 1.3 with WSO2 Identity provider.

**Problem:** Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token

**Question:** What is missing in my code/configuration in order to obtain the Access Token.

**application.yml**

```
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            clientId: 6kRDeCMVKjYzH7duL33AFAYX8dka
            clientSecret: USEZhqRyCfF_dIdEIjFolFOkTAoa
            accessTokenUri: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
            userAuthorizationUri: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
        resource:
schema=openid
            userInfoUri: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

**Application.groovy**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }

    @Bean public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/login' matched by universal pattern '/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?code=4ccb21df259c452e187421d46b984cf3&state=ioU1XC at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?code=4ccb21df259c452e187421d46b984cf3&state=ioU1XC at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@67c3c622. A new one will be created.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?code=4ccb21df259c452e187421d46b984cf3&state=ioU1XC at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@681bd9a9
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?code=4ccb21df259c452e187421d46b984cf3&state=ioU1XC at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?code=4ccb21df259c452e187421d46b984cf3&state=ioU1XC at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?code=4ccb21df259c452e187421d46b984cf3&state=ioU1XC at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@1ed9d99c
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler - No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

**Problem:** Since I'm using the WSO2 Identity Server in development mode, with an self-signed certificate, Java don't trust on it. And, in some HTTP request to WSO2 endpoints, connection fails by this invalid certificate.

**Temporary solution:** Turn off SSL checking in your development mode.

**Solution:** In a production environment, make sure that you WSO2 Identity Server has a valid certificate.

Comment: which plugins did you use for oAuth?